# How to solve this sequential async task problem in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-promise

In the below code snippet ths tasks are an object of tasks and the function defination should be such a way that the expected output should match.

```
    Let tasks = {
        ‘a’: {
            job: function(finish){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(‘A done’)
                    finish();
                }, 5000)
            },
            dependencies: []
        },
        ‘b’: {
            job: function(finish){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(‘B done’)
                    finish();
                }, 2000)
            },
            dependencies: []
        },
        ‘c’: {
            job: function(finish){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(‘C done’)
                    finish();
                }, 2000)
            },
            dependencies: [‘a’, ‘b’]
        },
        ‘d’: {
            job: function(finish){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(‘D done’)
                    finish();
                }, 1000)
            },
            dependencies: []
        },
        ‘e’: {
            job: function(finish){
                setTimeout(() => {
                    console.log(‘E  done’)
                    finish();
                }, 2000)
            },
            dependencies: [‘c’, ‘b’]
        },
    };

// implement a executeTasks function which can be invoked like below

executeTasks(tasks, function(){
    console.log(‘all done’);
})


function executeTasks(taskList, callback) {
    // write your code here
}

// Expected output

D done
B done
A done
C done
E done
All done
```

the function **executeTasks** will take a tasklist as shown example on the top and also a callback. The nature of the function is that the tasks will be executed with considering all the dependencies and once all tasks are executed the passed callback should invoke. The expected output is an example how the result will be for that given task list.

Answer (score 0):

Use `rxjs`,  `forkJoin`  might help you do it gracefully. https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin

Comment: Hey.. It was asked in a interview question and was asked to solve in vanilla js.

Comment: Then you should look more at Promise.all and Promise.then